# Javascript to calculate shopping cart totals

Tags: javascript, paypal

I currently have code for user to select shirt size, design, style and color. I am trying to get it to compute price based on user selection. If size is s,m,lg,xl the price is $10 but if they select 2x, 3x, the price is now $11, $12 respectively. The base price is for a t-shirt $10, but if the user selects long sleeve, then the base price is now $15. So then sizes 2x and 3x becomes $16, $17.

I also need be able to charge a flat shipping of $5 if order is have sizes from small to XL but charge if $8.00 order contains shirt with size 2xl or 3xl.

I hope this make sense. Any help editing the javascript is greatly appreciated.

```
<SCRIPT language=javascript>
function CalculateOrder(form)
{

if (form.os0.value == "S")
 {
 form.amount.value = 10.00;
 form.item_number.value = "Small";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }
 
if (form.os0.value == "M")
 {
 form.amount.value = 10.00;
 form.item_number.value = "W-T-Medium";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }

if (form.os0.value == "LG")
 {
 form.amount.value = 10.00;
 form.item_number.value = "W-T-LG";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }

if (form.os0.value == "XL")
 {
 form.amount.value = 10.00;
 form.item_number.value = "W-T-XL";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }
 
if (form.os0.value == "2XL")
 {
 form.amount.value = 11.00;
 form.item_number.value = "W-T-2XL";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }
 
if (form.os0.value == "3XL")
 {
 form.amount.value = 12.00;
 form.item_number.value = "W-T-3XL";
 if (form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"){
 form.shipping.value = "0.00";
 }
 if (form.os2.value == "USPS Priority Mail"){
 form.shipping.value = "8.00";
 }
 }
 
}  
</SCRIPT>

<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
             <div align="center">
                <p>
                  <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Design">
                  Design:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select name="os1">
                    <option value="Design1">Design1</option>
                    <option value="Design2">Design2</option>
                    <option value="Design3">Design3</option>
                    
                  </select>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style">
                  Style:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select name="os1">
                    <option value="T-shirt">T-shirt</option>
                    <option value="Long Sleeve">Long Sleeve</option>
                    
                  </select>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size">
                  Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <SELECT name="os0">
                    <OPTION value="S">S</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="M">M</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="LG">LG</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="XL">XL</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="2XL">2XL</OPTION>
                    <OPTION value="3XL">3XL</OPTION>            
                                        
                  </SELECT>
                  <br><br>
                  <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Color">
                  Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  <select name="os1">
                    <option value="Black">Black</option>
                    <option value="White">White</option>                    
                  </select>
                  
                  <br>Select Delivery Method:&nbsp;&nbsp;
               <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Delivery Method">
               <select name="os2">
               <option value="Pick Up" selected>Pick Up</option>
               <option value="USPS Priority Mail">USPS Priority Mail</option>
               </select>

                  <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
                  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
                  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget - T-Shirt">
                  <input type="hidden" name="amount">
                  <input type="hidden" name="item_number">
                  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
              <input type="hidden" name="shipping">
                  <input type="hidden" name="shipping2">
                  <INPUT onclick=CalculateOrder(this.form) type=image alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" 
                 src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border=0 name="submit">
                  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                  <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://abc123.com/store.html">
                  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.abc123.com/">
                  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
                  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
                  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">
                </p>
              </div>
</FORM>
```

Comment: Are you having issues with the JavaScript?  Or are you trying to just clean up your code?

Comment: The javascript wont adjust totals based on my what I described above. I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to clean up your code a little.

My changes and notes:

- added ID to form (`payment_form`), so we can search for it with `document.getElementById`
- you code is checking for `form.os2.value == "Store Pick-Up"`, but no such value in `os2` selector, take a look: `<option value="Pick Up" selected>` (see? it has different value)
- your block of checking `shipping` is the same for all `if's`, so I will pu tit in the end
- I will not pass a form to function, but search for it inside with: `const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');`
- `amount` is not correct name for prices, because `amount` is how many of this items do you need, it is not the price, but this is just a note. not important for now
- added IDs for selects, note: ID must be unique
- now all values updated if any select is updated with: `onchange="CalculateOrder()"`
- I've added new function `getOption` to get values that are set inside the `option` elements in `data-*` attributes
- I've changed function on the button to be `onclick="showTest(event)"` - this is just for testing. In you real code you do not need any `onclick` here.

```js
function getOption(select, dataAttr) {
  const option = select.options[select.selectedIndex];
  if (option) {
    return option.getAttribute(dataAttr);
  }
  return '';
}

function CalculateOrder() {
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  const os0 = document.getElementById('os0');
  const os1 = document.getElementById('os1');
  const os2 = document.getElementById('os2');

  let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));
  let item_number = getOption(os0, 'data-item-number');
  let shipping = getOption(os2, 'data-price');

  if (os0.value == "2XL") {
    price = price + 1;
  } else if (os0.value == "3XL") {
    price = price + 2;
  }

  if (os1.value == "Long Sleeve") {
    shipping = 8;
  }

  form.shipping.value = shipping;
  form.item_number.value = item_number;
  form.amount.value = price;
}

CalculateOrder()

function showTest(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const form = document.getElementById('payment_form');
  console.log('item number: ' + form.item_number.value, 'price: ' + form.amount.value, 'shipping: ' + form.shipping.value)
}
```

```html
<form target="_self" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="payment_form" onchange="CalculateOrder()">
  <div align="center">
    <p>
      <input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Design"> Design:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1">
        <option value="Design1">Design1</option>
        <option value="Design2">Design2</option>
        <option value="Design3">Design3</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on1" value="Style"> Style:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1" id="os1">
        <option value="T-shirt" data-base-price="10">T-shirt</option>
        <option value="Long Sleeve" data-base-price="15">Long Sleeve</option>
      </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Size"> Size:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <SELECT name="os0" id="os0">
        <OPTION value="S" data-item-number="Small">S</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="M" data-item-number="W-T-Medium">M</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="LG" data-item-number="W-T-LG">LG</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="XL" data-item-number="W-T-XL">XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="2XL" data-item-number="W-T-2XL">2XL</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="3XL" data-item-number="W-T-3XL">3XL</OPTION>
      </SELECT>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="on3" value="Color"> Color:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <select name="os1">
        <option value="Black">Black</option>
        <option value="White">White</option>
      </select>

      <br>Select Delivery Method:&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Delivery Method">
      <select name="os2" id="os2">
        <option value="Pick Up" selected data-price="0">Pick Up</option>
        <option value="USPS Priority Mail" data-price="5">USPS Priority Mail</option>
      </select>

      <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
      <input type="hidden" name="business" value="test@gmail.com">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Widget - T-Shirt">
      <input type="hidden" name="amount">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_number">
      <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping">
      <input type="hidden" name="shipping2">
      <INPUT onclick="showTest(event)" type=image alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border=0 name="submit">
      <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
      <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://abc123.com/store.html">
      <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.abc123.com/">
      <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
      <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
      <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF">
    </p>
  </div>
</FORM>
```

If you need more explanation, just ask.

P.S. You can test code by clicking "Run code snippet", then select values in selects and press a button.

Comment: This looks awesome..Will this add shipping each time I add to cart? should only be one shipping charge. Ooops I realize I didn't mention shipping. Was trying charge fixed shipping of $5 if order does not include a long sleeve. If it does the fixed charge would be  $8.   I notice when tried to use this code in my application, I get an error on this line "let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));"

Comment: @BBlyden this part I do not understand. You need to change the price of shipping? You mean "USPS" of "Pickup"?

Comment: The user should be able to choose to pickup the order. If they choose USPS, it should default to $5, but if the order contains a long sleeve, then the shipping will be $8

Comment: @BBlyden updated USPS price to 5, for Long sleeve 8.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work when I apply it to my page. Would it have anything to do with the syntax error on "  let price = parseFloat(getOption(os1, 'data-base-price'));"

Comment: @BBlyden did you checked the HTML also? `data-base-price` is a part of options now: `<option value="T-shirt" data-base-price="10">T-shirt</option>` (same change for Long sleeve)

Comment: yes... I just copied entire code as you have it and it flags that one line. The add to cart doesn't do anything like it does on the run code snippet  here. Could just be me. Will keep playing with it.

Comment: code works, even with the syntax error. Is there any way I can stop additional shipping charges being added to the cart? There should only be one flat rate of either $5 or $8

Comment: @BBlyden I think this will be another question. We know nothing about your shopping cart. I've tried to solve only `form`. For shopping cart we need a lot more information from you. For example, the backend code (because it is normal that only backend knows everything about the cart).

Comment: Thank you for your help... Really appreciate it.